# SOQL Query: Stored XSS Error

Tags: security, dynamic-soql, stored-xss

I have given my code for Security code Scanner but it is given the following error due to

> Query: Stored XSS

My query is like this.

```
loan=Database.query('SELECT Name, fintechLLC__Application__c, '+
                          'fintechLLC__Legal_Corporate_Name__c, '+
                          'fintechLLC__Last_Month_Trans__c, '+
                          'fintechLLC__X2_Month_ago_Trans_del__c, '+
                          'fintechLLC__X3_Month_ago_Trans__c, '+
                          'CreatedDate,fintechLLC__Monthly_Ending_Bal__c,Max_Rate__c, '+
                          'fintechLLC__Term__c,fintechLLC__Funding_Amount__c, '+
                          'fintechLLC__Business_DBA_Name__c,fintechLLC__Credit_Score__c, '+
                          'fintechLLC__Business_DBA_Years_in_Business__c, '+
                          'fintechLLC__Avg_Daily_Bank_Bal__c '+
                    'FROM fintechLLC__Loan__c '+
                    'WHERE id=\''+loanId+'\'');
```

Kindly help me in this

Comment: Is there any specific requirement for using Dynamic SOQL rather than standard SOQL?

Answer (score 2):

What is type of `loanId` and where does it code from? Is it a `String` or an `Id`?

Since you are using it to build a dynamic SOQL query you need to be extremely cautious with it. Especially since you have lots of terms like "Loan", "Bank", "Bal", "Credit_Score" in there.

For example, if it was a string from the URL query string I could try setting it to something like:

```
string loanId = '\' or ID!=\'\'';
```

Now that query will return all the `fintechLLC__Loan__c` records.

Is there a reason you need to use dynamic SOQL? As an alternative, you could use inline SOQL and using the `Id` type for `loanId` if you aren't already.

```
Id loanId = \\...
List<fintechLLC__Loan__c> loans = [SELECT Name, fintechLLC__Application__c,
                        fintechLLC__Legal_Corporate_Name__c, 
                        fintechLLC__Last_Month_Trans__c,
                        fintechLLC__X2_Month_ago_Trans_del__c,
                        fintechLLC__X3_Month_ago_Trans__c,
                        CreatedDate,fintechLLC__Monthly_Ending_Bal__c,Max_Rate__c,
                        fintechLLC__Term__c,fintechLLC__Funding_Amount__c,
                        fintechLLC__Business_DBA_Name__c,fintechLLC__Credit_Score__c,
                        fintechLLC__Business_DBA_Years_in_Business__c,
                        fintechLLC__Avg_Daily_Bank_Bal__c 
                FROM fintechLLC__Loan__c 
                WHERE id=:loanId 
                limit 1];
```

Now it would only be possible to have an Id go into that query. Since you are asking for a single record, your could be extra cautious and add a `limit` as well. This is mostly superfluous though.

See also: [SOQL Injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm)

Comment: loanID is a String where i am storing the RecordId

Comment: Change it to be a strongly typed `Id` rather than a string and avoid the dynamic SOQL (`Database.query`) unless you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

your dynamic query will fail to read loanId and also instead of using Database.query(query) use the below method to get dynamic soql query result as list

Syntax should be like ..

```
List<custom_object> cu_list = [Select id, name from custom_object where id=:loanId]
```